# How to Remove Sprinkler Stains from Vinyl Siding

Tags: siding, well, sprinkler-system, vinyl-siding

I have a sandpoint well that is used by my sprinkler system. I've noticed that the sprinklers leave a white residue on my siding that I have not been able to get off. I did some research online and tried the following:

- Pressure Washer
- Vinegar
- Goof Off iron remover
- Cleaning with soapy water and a brush

None of that seemed to make any progress. Are there any other options or is the siding permanently stained?

[image: white buildup on grey siding]
[image: white buildup on tan siding]

Comment: what is the siding material?  vinyl? aluminium?

Comment: @Jasen Vinyl siding

Answer (score 1):

As it's vinyl you can use muriatic acid to remove lime stains

If it were aluminium you'd have to use a proprietry lime scale remover as muriatic acid dissolves aluminium very well.

wear waterproof gloves and eye protection, rinse any drops that fall to the ground off the foundation and paving, follow safety directions etc.

Comment: I would start with a diluted solution but I agree, muriatic acid might do the trick and vinyl should not be affected. Maybe 1 part acid 3 parts acid increasing strength as needed.